# Jlist Not Updating From Method Call

Tags: java, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am having a problem with updating components in a separate GUI class from my main. I have done a lot of research and all of the solutions I found have not worked. In the GUI class, I have a JList that I want to populate from the main running program as it completes tasks. I have tried using .setModel() in a plethora of ways and none have worked

GUI Class

```
public class statusGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  private DefaultListModel listModel; 

  private void initComponents() {

    statusList = new javax.swing.JList<>();

    statusList.setModel(listModel);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(statusList);

    /* Removed a lot of formatting code */

    pack();
  }                        

private javax.swing.JList<String> statusList;                 

  public statusGUI() {

    //statusList = new JList(listModel);
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    listModel.addElement("Hello");
    initComponents();
    listModel.addElement("Test");
    statusList.setModel(listModel);

  }

  public void addUpdateToList(String updateMsg){

    listModel.addElement(updateMsg);
    System.out.print(listModel.size() + ",");
    System.out.print(listModel.get(listModel.size()-1) + ",");

    statusList.setModel(listModel);  

    //statusList.revalidate();
    //this.revalidate();
    //this.repaint();
  }
}
```

MAIN Class

```
public static void main(String[] args){

  statusGUI status = new statusGUI();
  status.startGUI();

  status.addUpdateToList("Stack");
  status.addUpdateToList("Overflow");
}
```

So after running the main, my list populates with "Hello" and "Test". But the two print methods return 4, Hello, 5, Overflow. So the DefaultListModel listModel is getting updated but is not refreshing like I've read online that it's supposed to do. I have also tried adding a button with an ActionListener that does statusList.setModel(listModel) but to no avail. This also occurs with a Label on the form...I am unable to change the Label's text outside of the class. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a random thought, but have you tried removing this line from `addUpdateToList`: `statusList.setModel(listModel);` ?

Comment: If I remove the line you are referencing and only have the line `listModel.addElement(updateMsg);` it still does not add the new entries from the main.